# Flutter 1.12 app crashes on iPhone 4S (iOS 9.3.6) device

Tags: flutter, release

I have an app that recently I have updated to Flutter 1.12. Once I have pushed the release to Apple Store, I have reported a crash from one of my users - they have an iPhone 4S (iOS 9.3.6) device.
Prior that when my app was built with **Flutter v1.9.1+hotfix.6** I have no such issues. 
Here is my `flutter doctor -v` output:

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.14.6
>   18G1012,
>       locale en-GB)
>       • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at /Users/angel/development/flutter
>       • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (6 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
>       • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
>       • Dart version 2.7.0
>
> [✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
>       ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
>         Install Android Studio from:
>         https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
>         On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
>         components.
>         (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
>         instructions).
>         If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, set
>         ANDROID_HOME to that location.
>         You may also want to add it to your PATH environment variable.
>
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
>       • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
>       • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
>       • CocoaPods version 1.8.4
>
> [!] Android Studio (not installed)
>       • Android Studio not found; download from
>         https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
>         (or visit https://flutter.dev/setup/#android-setup for detailed
>         instructions).
>
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.43.0)
>       • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
>       • Flutter extension version 3.8.1

I realize the feedback I am giving you guys is limited, however, since I have no such hardware in the possession and in general I have no much of experience with iOS devices, I would appreciate any advice how to proceed on this topic. 
Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to say what is causing the crash just by looking at the `flutter doctor` output. Maybe there is some plugin causing crash only on v1.12, hard to say without proper crash logs. Please find a way to get crash logs and post it here.

Comment: @HasilT - any tips on how to get crash logs from the iPhone 4S? The user is quite cooperative and they will try to assist, if I can prove a simple instructions...